# Can RSpec be used as a bruteforcing mechanism?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Little by little i begin to understand the power of Rspec, though i still do not see why i would need to use it to test controllers or views (i'm sure there are reasons behind it).

I'm creating a browser game where users attack monsters. In my head, Rspec would be really really useful if it could provide a bruteforcing mechanism for me. For instance, let's say that i want to have a certain user fight all the monsters one by one and provide some conditions that will trigger the tests to fail.

For example, if a user fights a monster of the same level, hp, and about the same strength, it would be really weird if he/she is killed while the monster still has more than 70% of its hp (that's just a scenario).

It seems to me that this kind of behaviour is tested with rspec in combination with cucumber ? I would really like to get some insight on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that the example you give is well suited for Cucumber. You are trying to test what happens when a user fights a certain monster. You would set up each scenario and then go through steps to exercise various portions of the user experience.

rSpec is for unit testing, i.e. making sure that each method of your models, controllers and views does the proper thing and gives you proper results. By definition, a unit test isolates itself to the code you are test so, for example, if a controller method needs data from a model, that data is mocked or stubbed for each condition of the method being tested. That way your test is not affected by other parts of the code not really under test.